# TeamCity Build Agent failed to create build checkout directory

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am using TeamCity to build a project from SVN.

Every time I tried to build my project, it always show me the message below:
Build errors
 [13:11:57]: Agent failed to create build checkout directory at C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\https:\192.168.10.66\svn\WMSHelperCE\trunk. Please check agent has necessary permissions and there is enough free space on disk.

However, I was looking for the answer on internet, but still doesn't work.
Anyone can tell me about how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you ping your server from the TeamCity box?, The TeamCity agent user is a domain user with permissions in the remote server? Try checking out the repository manually in the box server in another location just to check connectivity.

Comment: Yes, I can ping the server from TeamCity box.
I have assigned full control permission for TeamCity Service with EveryOne, Network Service and Local Service. But still doesn't work.

Comment: What version of TeamCity are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to set the build agent to do its work on a remote computer (`C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\https:\192.168.10.66\svn\WMSHelperCE\trunk`) which has corrupted the path. I don't know if this is actually possible, is there a reason you want this as you don't want to be sharing the build agents work folder with other build agents. Teamcity will either instruct the build agents to pull the source code or it will send it to them based on your setup.

To fix this You need to edit the [build agents property file](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Agent+Configuration) and set the `workDir` and probably the `tempDir` property to be a local path, it can be relative or absolute.

**EDIT**

After looking at your path again it looks like you are trying to set the work path to your projects repository. This is not how it should be done. You build needs to suck down the project from your repository and the build is done locally on the build agent. Check out the help page on setting up a [builds version control](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Configuring+VCS+Settings).